# How do you Benzylate (add a benzene group to) cyclic compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, aromatic-compounds

How do you add a benzene group to cyclic compounds like piperidine, piperazine and phenyl derivatives?

#### Piperidine

[image]

#### Piperazine

[image]

Comment: You could try halogenation on it (to create partial positive on some carbon ($\large\ce{\delta}$ $^+$)) and then add $\ce{Phenyl\ Magnesium\ Halide\  (Ph-Mg-X)}$(Grignard's reagent) to subtitute halide group on ring nucleophilically with Benzene, although that would be difficult/not feasible to carry out in phenyl derivatives.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that benzylpiperazine is a schedule 9 (banned) substance in Australia and whilst good faith is assumed (nothing wrong with academic interest), people might be loath to address such a specific reaction.

Comment: Your good faith is right I have no intention in synthesising such a compound. This is such a simple curiousity

Comment: Do you mean a compound like [this](http://www.clipular.com/c?1714105=Fg9BRhFE8yzr65b5gVwWyXjqsXQ), or [this](http://www.clipular.com/c?1714106=TSvpqZc6arn-wrOMxlOQHlvw-Bw) or [this](http://www.clipular.com/c?1709098=7J6D5r7yR8kvdl4j8b5J0sOnhho) ot [this](http://www.clipular.com/c?1718063=WSkFbyWwVKZF7fZoWQ0qg4__dO8), out of piperidine.

Comment: (1) & (3), no, that's a phenylpiperidine, (2), compounds like, yes, but not (2) because that's 4-benzylpiperidine -- a stimulant and likely addictive drug, (4), yes.

Comment: Well, (4) is pretty easy to make, you take Benzyl-halide along with a Lewis Acid(like $\ce{AlCl3}$ or $\ce{FeCl3}$) and since Nitogen is a nucleophile it will easily attack on piperidine on the generated carbocation. By the way (4) is also a benzyl derivative not phenyl derivative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brenton, the term "benzene group" is a bit misleading; it seems that you'd like to add a benzyl group, i.e. $\ce{C6H5-CH2}$.

Typically, these reaction are carried out using freshly distilled benzyl halides. In the case of the diamines, monoalkylation is usually achieved using the bis-hydrochloride of the amine and a stochiometric amount of base, thus keeping one nitrogen atom protected.

Note however, that the Australian regulations, kindly mentioned by Richard Terrett, are likewise true in the EC: 1-benzylpiperazine, an infamous psychoactive party drug, is a controlled substance!